# ATI HD Missing Driver On Official Site

Tags: drivers, ati, video, fglrx

Can someone give me a hand with a HD 4650 SAPPHIRE driver?
I searched on the official site and this is what I get:

AMD Catalyst™ Driver for AMD Radeon™ HD 4000, HD 3000 and HD 2000 Series

AMD has moved to the AMD Radeon™ HD 4000, AMD Radeon HD 3000, and AMD Radeon HD 2000 Series new driver support model.(...)

Applicable Products:

This article applies to the following configuration(s):
Hardware:

AMD Radeon HD 4000 Series /
AMD Radeon HD 3000 Series /
AMD Radeon HD 2000 Series /
AMD Radeon HD Series AGP /
AMD Mobility Radeon HD 4000 Series /
AMD Mobility Radeon HD 3000 Series /
AMD Mobility Radeon HD 2000 Series /

And a link to a single driver:
AMD Catalyst™ 12.6 Proprietary Linux x86 Display Driver
(Automated installer and Display Drivers for X.Org 6.7, 6.8, 6.9, 7.0, 7.1, 7.2, 7.3, 7.4, 7.5, or 7.6)

Last time I installed this driver it gaved me some error (can't remember what it was) and I couldn't install nothing no more due to some FGLRX & dpgk error. Any solutions?

Comment: Wish me luck! I'm rebooting the computer now. I couldn't wait any longer so I installed the driver manually from the official site this time without errors. I'll come with an add after rebooting.

Comment: #ADD: well, it looks like it's working (the gnome theme has that dash active again) but I can seem to activate the window effects...They are thiked in the Compiz Manager, but not working...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### You need to remove all the current fglrx packages from your system

if any of these returns errors ie: file not found, package not found **ignore it**

Type in terminal Ctrl-Alt-T

```
sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh

sudo apt-get remove --purge fglrx fglrx_* fglrx-amdcccle* fglrx-dev*
```

Once this is done follow [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/124292/what-is-the-correct-way-to-install-ati-catalyst-video-drivers/126513#126513) to install the correct driver from the officical AMD site

OR

If you want to install the Official ubuntu binarys go-to **System Settings >> Additional Drivers** and select the Driver thats recommended

Answer (score 0):

Open the Dash,

Search for **Additional Drivers**.

Open it.

And Activate the driver if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If Varun's suggestion fails (in my case it did) you can install the drivers manually.

A nice step-by-step explanation can be found at http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Installation_Guide